# Why do I get different results during ftp communication when using ls filename and ls./filename

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I am connecting to a proftd server as client and try to list files. I use ls command with two different parameters:

1. `ls filename`

   ```
   ftp> ls test.txt  
   229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||41257|)  
   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list  
   -rw-r-----   1 myftpuser (?)          9939 Jul 13 09:38 test.txt  
   226 Transfer complete.  
   ftp>
   ```
2. `ls ./filename`

   ```
   ftp> ls ./test.txt  
   229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||41257|)  
   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list  
   226 Transfer complete.  
   ftp>
   ```

I am in the right directory in both case.
Why do I get 2 different result?

Comment: Do you know which version of ProFTPD is being used?

Comment: ProFTPD Version 1.3.0

Comment: ProFTPD 1.3.0 is _very_ old; I suspect that this is a bug which has been fixed in newer releases.  The current stable version is 1.3.5b.  Could you upgrade your server, and try again?

Comment: I will discuss with the guy who is operation the server. Has somebody never version than 1.3.0 who could do a test for me?

Comment: I have tested with 1.3.4a but the same :(

Comment: Turns out this is a real bug in ProFTPD; see [Bug#4259](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4259).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a real bug in ProFTPD; see [Bug#4259](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4259).